# WebdriverIO - cannot run examples data sets in parallel

Tags: typescript, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, webdriver-io, parallel-testing

I have a webdriverio/TS/Cucumber project in which there is one feature file, one scenario outline, and some examples rows at the end. The glue code/spec file is also a single file.
Can someone guide me how I can run the examples in parallel having 2 or more instances of chrome browser taking the test data from the examples rows - one by one - I mean first worker picks first row and second picks second and so on. Thank you.

I tried it with selenium standalone service provided by Webdriverio. But I got no clue as to how I can connect my 2 workers of chrome browsers with two different rows in the examples rows.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.